# Is there a term for this subtraction formula?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

Is there a term for this concept? Any link?

n is a decimal from 0 to 1, including

FORMULA

```
n = 0.5
x = 1 - n
```

EXAMPLES

```
1.0 => 0.0
0.8 => 0.2
0.5 => 0.5
0.3 => 0.7
0.0 => 1.0
```

I have this use case all the time and would like a term for it.

Comment: This seems to be a Math question, not a *Mathematica* question.

Comment: In other words, you want to know if the functions $f(x) = 1-x$ has a special name?

Comment: yes. i'd use that term in programming, could not come up with a short meaningful name myself and was wondering if there is one already.

Comment: in addition to your function, as written in the question: x ∈ [0,1]

Comment: Another notable example: in fuzzy logic (continuous probability instead of true/false) this function replaces the "not" operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map $\,x\mapsto 1-x\,$ is known as the *reflection* (or *inversion*) of $\,x$ across the point $\,1/2,\,$ see for example the  [Wikipedia page on point reflections.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_reflection) If we  shift $\,1/2\,$ to the origin by changing variables $\ x = z+1/2\ $ then it is simply the reflection through $\,0,\,$ i.e.  $\,z\mapsto -z,\,$ i.e. negation.